# Why isn't my select list selected option being set when using knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm able to successfully set the options for my select list but the selected option isn't being set.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/devlife/YmshY/2/

Html:

```
<select data-bind="options: FundTypeOptions, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', value:
```

Javscript:

```
$root.SelectedFundType"></select>​

$(function(){

    var options = {
        "ImportType":0,

        "ImportTypeList":{
            "":"",
            "Funds":"Fund Level Investments",
            "Valuations":"Valuations"
        },

        "FundTypeOptions":[
            {"Value":"","Text":""},
            {"Value":"Initial","Text":"Initial"},
            {"Value":"FollowOn","Text":"Follow-on"}
        ],

        "SelectedImportType":"Funds",

        SelectedFundType: "FollowOn"
    };

    var viewModel = {

        FundTypeOptions: ko.observableArray(options.FundTypeOptions)

    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});​
```

Comment: your JS fiddle is throwing error "ko is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SelectedFundType is not a property of your viewModel.

```
var viewModel = {

    FundTypeOptions: ko.observableArray(options.FundTypeOptions),
    SelectedFundType: ko.observable("FollowOn")
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h8mfK/1/

Hope this helps.